# Rails Validation based on presence of some attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to create a validation on a model. The model has two attributes `private_key` and `public_key`. If the user provides either one I want the validation to make sure that the other is provided. So if they provide the `public_key` they must provide the `private_key` and vice versa. Right now I have the following:

```
validates_presence_of :public_key if :private_key?
validates_presence_of :private_key if :public_public?
```

For some reason if I don't provide either I am getting an error.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

use `if` like attribute, not like condition:

```
validates_presence_of :public_key, if: :private_key?
validates_presence_of :private_key, if: :public_public?
```

Comment: YAY! thank you! I wish I could mark both as correct though since you both answered at the same time

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
validates_presence_of :public_key, if: 'private_key?'
validates_presence_of :private_key, if: 'public_public?'
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be proper syntax

Comment: Sorry, missed the commas.

Comment: YAY! thank you! I wish I could mark both as correct though since you both answered at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *validates* shortcut method, which allows you to tuck in  multiple validations later on the same attribute if needed:

```
validates :public_key, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |r| r.private_key.present? }
validates :private_key, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |r| r.public_key.present? }
```

I would prefer to test the presence of an attribute explicitly, for example using public_key.present? rather than public_key? as it is more readable and AFAIK public_key? method is only available for boolean fields, unless you defined.